# How to display only last occurrance of an element?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have dynamically generating  I only need to display the last div. How can I achieve this?

Comment: used to this div:last-child{display:block;}  div{display:none;}

Comment: Depends on how you're generating it dynamically. If you dont need to show the others ever and are using a foreach loop (in php for example). You can already disable the whole generating except for the last element. Just a offtopic suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("div").hide();
$("div").last().show();
```

Hide all the `div` and then show the `last` one.

or

```
$("div:not(:last)").hide();
```

or

```
$("div").slice(-1).hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the syntax of CSS 3, you could use the ***:not*** selector combined with ***:nth-last-child***  selector:

```
div:not(:nth-last-child(1)) {
    display: none;
}
```

***:not*** selector

The **:nth-last-child(*n*)** selector matches every element is the *n*th child, regardless of type, of its parent, counting from the last child.

The **:not(*selector*)** selector matches every element that is NOT the specified element/selector.

***:not*** and ***:nth-last-child*** selectors works under:

- Chrome >= 4.0
- IE >= 9.0
- Firefox >= 3.5
- Safari >= 3.2
- Opera >= 9.6

Answer (score 0):

HI now used to this only css  `last-child`

```css
#dynamicData >div{display:none;}


#dynamicData >div:last-child{display:block;}
```

```html
<div id="dynamicData">

<div>0</div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5 last div </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with CSS:

**HTML (example of dynamically generated output):**

```
<div class="item">content</div>
<div class="item">content</div>
<div class="item">content</div>
<div class="item">content</div>
<div class="item">content</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.item {
    display: none;
}
.item:last-child {
    display: block;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/zn32s7db/2/